# Dockerizing a Selenium web scraper

Tags: python, docker, selenium

I'm trying to containerize my script to run on the cloud because it simply takes too long to run on my local machine. It works fine on my machine without Docker but when I try to run it as a Docker image, it's not able to scrape the necessary data I need.

I've already added chrome options to be able to run it with Docker but it's still not able to scrape properly.

```
df = pd.read_csv('restos.csv')
links = list(df['resto_links'])
coordinates = []
links_processed = 0

for i in links:

    options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1024,768')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

    driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(i)
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/ubuntu/Documents/1-MARKETING/location-analysis/chromedriver')
    # driver.get(i)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    try:
        maps_link = soup.select_one('a[href*=google]')['href']
        coordinates.append(maps_link)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    links_processed += 1
    print('Progress: {}/{} links processed'.format(links_processed, len(links)))
    print(coordinates)
```

Comment: How do you dockerize it? What does it mean "it's not able to scrape the necessary data I need"?

Comment: I have a Dockerfile to build the image. I get NoneType error. But when I run it outside of Docker, it gets the links I'm scraping